# Personalizar atributos de placeholder en Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, rápido

Solito la ayuda de profesionales en el tema de personalizar el componente de placeholder en swift xcode. He colocado un código para ubicar un icono en la zona izquierda del texto, sin embargo esta se desborda del lugar donde la ubico. He intentado ajustar valores numéricos y no me funciona, a continuación anexo el codigo e imagen del resultado, sin embargo, quiero aprovechar el espacio también para preguntar si existe la posibilidad de cambiar el color del placeholder, asi mismo crear un padding left para separarlo un poco del icono, muchas gracias.

```
func addLeftImg (txtField: UITextField, andImage img: UIImage) {
    
let leftImgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height))
    
leftImgView.image = img
txtField.leftView = leftImgView
txtField.leftViewMode = .always

}
```

este codigo lo aplico en el placeholder de la siguiente manera.

```
 let userNameImg = UIImage(named: "ink1")
addLeftImg(txtField: userNameTextField, andImage: userNameImg!)
```

y claramente el resultado no deseado es el siguiente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para separar el placeholder de la imagen usa edgeInsets de la clase UIEdgeInsets, tambien el textfield tiene metodos y propiedades para eso:

```
 func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
 func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
 var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
```

para el color del placeholder es con la propiedad textField.attributedPlaceholder usando NSAttributeString, y para lo de la imagen del icono trata de usar el contentMode y sus atributos para poder darle bien el tamaño por ejemplpo,,, el renderingMode, o usar la propiedad scaleAspectFit, etc es estar probando.. saludos

igual te dejo una imagen para que te des una idea..

el padding es un simple CGFloat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, probare tu propuesta haber que tal...

Comment: ok, dale, si necesitas mas apoyo aquí estamos a la orden, saludos!

Comment: Eres el mejor! Muchas gracias amigo! Por favor tengo en mi perfil una pregunta mas sobre los nav Controller, podrías echar un vistazo para saber una posible solución? Te agradezco mucho.

Comment: ok la voy a revisar una chance que tenga saludos!